# sanitize a foreign entity when called in Java

Tags: java, sql, entity

I have a table that is generated from a database table. In that database table it has a foreign key linking it back to another database table. However when I print out the field it prints out the full path such as entity."" [""=""]. Is there a way to sanitize it so it will only return the result? I am trying to link to pages and things using the results number. Below in the tickets jsp page you will see I created a link on the sheetNum the directs you to viewBuyer?"buyerNum" however when you click the link instead of it going to say viewbuyer?1 it goes to viewBuyer?entity.BuyerInfo[ buyerNum=1 ]. I want to scrub out all the entity stuff and just be left with the value it is grabbing.

Servlet

```
case "/tickets":
            try{
                ticket = TicketDB.getTickets();
                request.setAttribute("ticket", ticket);

            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } break;
```

tickets.jsp

```
<div id="body">
                <table id="buyerTable">
                    <c:forEach var="ticket" items="${ticket}" varStatus="iter">
                        <tr class="${((iter.index % 2) == 0) ? 'grey' : 'white'}">
                            <td>
                                ${ticket.ticketId}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="viewBuyer?${ticket.buyerNum}">                                
                                ${ticket.sheetNum}
                                </a>
                                <br>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                ${ticket.lotNum}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                ${ticket.qty}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                ${ticket.price}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                ${ticket.description}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                ${ticket.buyerNum}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                ${ticket.paid}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                ${ticket.taxable}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                ${ticket.buyersPre}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                ${ticket.datePosted}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                ${ticket.dateUpdated}
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: What does the raw data look like?

Comment: When you saw raw data do you mean data I am entering in to it? If so it is the field names above. String ticketId, int sheetNum, int lotNum, int qty, BigDecimal price, String description, BuyerInfo buyerId, short paid, short taxable, short buyersPre, Date datePosted, Date dateUpdated. I enter in the following data 1-001, 1, 2, 3, 12.12, 1231, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2017-03-22 11:10:46,  2017-03-22 11:10:46

Comment: I'm asking what the raw data in your database looks like. Based on the description of your problem, it seems that you either have extraneous information in the db (the buyer number field should contain 1, rather than the string buyerNumber=1) or you are performing some transformation on that clean data to get the output you don't want, Which is it?

Comment: I am performing some transformation on the clean data I presume. in the db the buyer number field does contain 1 however it is a foreign key in the ticket table. So when I call upon the ticket.buyerNum field it is actually looking up the buyer number in the buyerInfo db table. I assume that is why it is calling upon the entity.buyerinfo to look up the buyer number. I assume it is then reporting back the location it grabbed the info from.